# How to get data from touchablewithoutfeedback onPress

Tags: react-native

I am parsing data from API, I want some part to show only when I click on the main part. I am first trying to alert it but it is showing null, however all other data is working, I am sure that `item.description`
is available but it is not working with onPress.

What I want to do is to that description only in  last `<Text>` when someone press the item itself.

```
     <FlatList
      data={this.state.data.articles}
      renderItem={
      ({item}) =>

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => { alert( item.description ) } }>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.item}>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.source}> {item.source.name} </Text>
            <Text> Description should be here and only showed when item clicked </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

      }
    />
```

Comment: Should `alert` be `Alert.alert`?

Comment: Alert.alert worked, thanks @Dan